# MacBook Air 2018 shutsdown after a few minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, crash, macos

My MacBook Air shutsdown after a few minutes. It doesn't seem matter what I do. The diagnostic utility reports 2 minutes remaining with the progress bar at about half way before it shutsdown.  The MacBook will run once for a few minutes and shutdown. The second time maybe 2 minutes. And then nothing until the next day and it will do the same thing. It is fully charged each time I try starting it. I've cleared Pram and NVRam. I tried booting from an Ubuntu Live USB.  What is the next diagnostic step?  No service centers for Mac anywhere nearby and shipping it somewhere for repair is very expensive.  I could get a mule to bring me a part if I can pin it down.

I appreciate your ideas!

Thank You,
Michael

Comment: Try Safe Mode, Recovery Mode, and Hardware Test

Comment: is this on power or battery? what does the console log say?